# show [] entries datatable change position

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables with Show[] entries at the top of the table. However, I would like to move it to the bottom.

Below is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ple').dataTable({
    "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-bottom"l>tip'
  });
});
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Answer (score 3):

From "https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html" =>

```
l - Length changing
f - Filtering input
t - The Table!
i - Information
p - Pagination
r - pRocessing
< and > - div elements
<"#id" and > - div with an id
<"class" and > - div with a class
<"#id.class" and > - div with an id and class
```

Here is the code that I used;

```
$('table.tableClass').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">'
  });
```

ps: (I don't use "i" : info, So if you need "i" add somewhere you desire);

ps2 : ('table.tableClass') is also taking care of multiple tables. You can use ('#tableID') for one table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the angular 2+ solution:

```
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
ngOnInit(): void {
this.dtOptions = {
  dom: 'frtlip'
};}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ple').DataTable({
    "sDom": 'Lfrtlip'                 
});
```

From this you can set to bottom.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ple').dataTable({
    bLengthChange: true,
    "sDom": 'Rlfrtlip',
  });
   //If it shows multiple show[] entries then use following line to hide top one
   //$("#machineStatusTabel_length:first").hide() 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Put B at the end of dom :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ple').dataTable({
    bLengthChange: true,
    "sDom": 'RlfrtlipB',
  });
   //If it shows multiple show[] entries then use following line to hide top one
   //$("#machineStatusTabel_length:first").hide() 
});
```